# How to prevent an user used only for integrations for logging in via interface?

Tags: integration, administration, user-management, accesstoken

In my ORG I have an user used for integrations purposes only. Some integrations are using oauth2 authentication so that third-party platforms connect to Salesforce directly. In other integrations was used an approach that the following settings were shared (The code snippet is in PHP):

```
$settings = array(
    "clientId" => "",
    "clientSecret" => "",
    "username" => "",
    "password" => "",
    "grantType" => "",
    "loginBaseURL" => "",
    "queryBaseURL" => "",
);


$oSyncSF = new SyncSF($settings);
$oSyncSF->setQuery($SOQL);

# Getting the response
$response = $oSyncSF->getData();

# Checking if there is a valid token
if ($oSyncSF->isToken()) 
{
    // gets the data
    $data = $oSyncSF->getData();

    //prints the data
    print_r($data);
}
```

Previously, this integration user was used for both **systems integrations** and as **an admin user**.

Today, the use as admin no longer makes sense. So, how to prevent this user from accessing the login screen without breaking the active integrations?

Someone who has had access to the credentials can gain access via https://login.salesforce.com/.

How to avoid that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to ensure that this "integration user" is set with the "[API Only](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000331470&type=1)" permission:

> API Only - Specifies that the user can only log in through the API. This prevents the user from being used for any purpose other than integration scenarios